# t4 Debuging: ReflectionTypeLoadException "Unable to load one or more of the requested types"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, t4

I have a custom T4 template.  When I right-click and select "Run Custom Tool" it run without error.  If I right-click and select "Debug T4 Template" I get the error above with the addition of

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = My.Interfaces, Version=1.0.5708.24057, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/My.Interfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/My.Interfaces/My.Interfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/My.Interfaces.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/My.Interfaces/My.Interfaces.EXE.
```

I am using the 'Assembly' directive with the fully qualified valid path from c:... to the dll.

```
<#@ Assembly Name="C:\...\MY.Interfaces.dll" #>
```

Again it does not error when not debugging.

My question is how do I get the debugger to properly import the assembly without copying it to the 'IDE' directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the dll I was referencing was the wrong version.  It was located in the bin directory of a project in the same solution.  I updated the dll and rebuilt that project.  It then worked, no need to put the dll anywhere else.

:\